# Edit sh script before a cron job starts running

Tags: shell-script, cron

I do not have much experience in Linux and would like some insight into whether there is a possibility to change a variable within a script before it is automatically started through a Cron Job.

For example, that the variable `VORDATE="04%2F15%2F2019"` would be changed (automatically) to one week prior to today, present in the variable `CURRENTDATE="09%2F09%2F2019"`.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your variable inside the script that you want to run in cron? would you explain more about your script?

Comment: Yes, inside. It is a download script, so it downloads data from week to week :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your cron job is going to run a bash script. Your script could use the `date` command to specify a relative date.

A week in the past

```
VORDATE=$(date -d "7 days ago")
```

A week in the future

```
VORDATE=$(date -d "7 days")
```

`man date` for more information.

edit: Howto format output

You can format the output by adding a format string by using the `+` option, the `%<codes>` are described in the manual page, to add a literal % use `%%` here's an example with spaces to aid reading.

```
$ date -d "7 days ago" +"%m %%2f %d %%2f %Y"
09 %2f 19 %2f 2019
```

Comment: should that be `-d "7 days ago"` ?

Comment: Oops, I thought @Bruna B wanted a week ahead, yes adding ago is last week, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @XTian hi, just one more question... it is possible to format the output date? Because it is part of a url, which means I need the `08%2F17%2F2019` format.